# MongoDB: how to query documents with `IS NOT(MAX())` criteria?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is a collection called `test`.

```
{
    {"_id": 1, "groupName": "A", lastModified: ISODate("2012-09-17T23:25:56.314Z")},
    {"_id": 2, "groupName": "A", lastModified: ISODate("2013-09-17T23:25:56.314Z")},
    {"_id": 3, "groupName": "A", lastModified: ISODate("2016-01-10T23:25:56.314Z")},
    {"_id": 4, "groupName": "B", lastModified: ISODate("2020-09-17T23:25:56.314Z")},
    {"_id": 5, "groupName": "B", lastModified: ISODate("2000-01-17T23:25:56.314Z")}
}
```

I want to query some documents within this collection, with these criteria:

1. whose `groupName` are "A".
2. whose `lastModified` are **not** the greatest value(`ISODate("2016-01-10T23:25:56.314Z")`) of the `lastModified` fields of the documents with `"groupName": "A"`.

So in this case, the result should be

```
{
    {"_id": 1, "groupName": "A", lastModified: ISODate("2012-09-17T23:25:56.314Z")},
    {"_id": 2, "groupName": "A", lastModified: ISODate("2013-09-17T23:25:56.314Z")}
}
```

I'm using Node.js with `node-mongodb-native` module.
Can I do it without fetching and iterating over the entire documents? I mean, can I do it within DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'll definitely filter by groupName, this simple query can help you achieve your desired result without much performance overhead.

`db.test.find({groupName : "A"}).skip(1).sort({lastModifiedAt : -1})`

If you have a more complex scenario/grouping/nesting however, you might need to use `aggregate` or `mapReduce` framework.

Comment: Thank you. But it seems that the purpose of the `.skip(1)` is to remove the grestest one, so it should be _sort-before-skip_ form. Shouldn't it be `db.test.find({groupName: "A"}).sort({lastModified: -1}).skip(1)`?

Comment: You're welcome. In writing a Mongo query, it does not matter. Mongo will always execute `sort`, then `skip`, then `limit`. That way the answer always make sense. Give it a try.

Comment: Thank you! It helped me a lot!